# NSwag generated C# clientsyntax errors

Tags: c#, swagger, nswag, nswagstudio

NSwag generates a very strange output with plenty of syntax errors (see sample below). Any ideas?

```
public virtual Response169 BusinessClassificationLovWhere(Country='')(Country2 country, int? top = null, int? skip = null, bool? count = null, string filter = null, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Anonymous808> orderby = null, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Anonymous809> select = null)
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await BusinessClassificationLovWhere(Country='')Async(country, top, skip, count, filter, orderby, select, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

I am using NSwagStudio 12.16.0.0